# Как правильно хранить Events в классах?

Tags: java, android

Я использую несколько пакетов в моём Android проекте.
Например:

> com.app.example->activities

> com.app.example->adapters

и другие.

Я хочу использовать классы с Events в разных пакетах, но могу ли я добавить их в один java файл?

Из-за области видимости я не могу сделать так:

```
public class Event1
{
        
}
    
class Event2
{
    
}
```

и так:

```
public class Event1
{
    
}
    
public class Event2
{
    
}
```

Думаю, что создавать для каждого события отдельный класс и файл не лучшая идея. Подскажите, как правильно хранить классы с событиями в проекте?

Comment: Java не позволяет размещать больше одного класса в файле. Уточните суть ваших  Events, это часть какой-то архитектуры?

Comment: Я использую библиотеку EventBus (github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) для которой создаю класс CustomEvent для каждого event, который использую. Например: LogOutEvent event = new LogOutEvent(); EventBus.getDefault().post(event); Если у меня будет 50 событий, придётся создавать 50 классов)